# Restoring large mySLQ dump with large blob

Tags: mysql, restore

I'm trying to download and restore a very large mySQL dump (>40GB) which also contains large binary blobs in tables.
I'm using a command line like this:

`curl 'https://url_from_doogle_dirve' -H ... --compressed | mysql --user=root --password=my-secret`

The operation starts but after about 57MB I get the following error:

`ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 388: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

I think I've read almost all threads about this error and tried many solutions but unfortunately none of them works for me

here is my `mysqld.cnf` file (relevant part only):

```
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M

net_write_timeout = 36000
net_read_timeout = 36000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M
wait_timeout = 36000
```

I had to increase `max_allowed_packet` to `32MB` because with `16MB`it previously failed with another error, but now I have this new `ERROR 2013` that seems related to large query / timeout. Actually, as stated above, tables contains binary blobs that may be even larger than 20 / 30 MB each.

**EDIT**

I've also tried downloading the sql file locally but I get the same result, so it has nothing to do with `curl`

MySQL 5.7.29 on Ubuntu Server 18.04.4

Comment: What MySQL version do you use? What is the operating system running your server?

Comment: @Jocelyn mySQL 5.7.29 on Ubuntu Server 18.04.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem thanks to maria-db.

I run the same command on mariadb server instead of mySQL server and I got the same issue but mariadb gave me a more meaningful error message:

`ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 388: The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size.`

So I set

`innodb_log_file_size=256M`

and it's now working (not finished yet but at least this issue has gone)
I guess it will work on mySQL server too.